SUMPRODUCT formula confusing performance in conditional conditional formatting
I use this sumproduct formula to check value between 2 sheets (sheet1 and Stopwork sheet) and to change the row color if result TRUE
=SUMPRODUCT(('Stop Work'!$D$8:$D$500=$C10)*('Stop Work'!$K$8:$K$500="Open")*('Stop Work'!$C$8:$C$500=$B$2)*($T$8:$T$500=$B$3))
my probelm is only in the last condition in the formula *($T$8:$T$500=$B$3)) to check if value in "T" in sheet1 ="B3" in the same sheet which is already BLANK - but what happen is when I put any data in "T" to make it not BLANK the condition doesn't apply while when I change cell "B3" to be not BLANK the condition works as you can see in the screenshot

can you tell me please what can i do
copy from the file to test

Please correct the formula since it's not correct now. List delimiters or asterisks can be omitted in it.

Guessing omitted list delimiters or asterisks, the formula counts the number of rows where "'Stop Work'!D" equals the current C cell and "'Stop Work'!K" equals "Open" and "'Stop Work'!C" equals "$B$2" and T equals "$B$3". Is it correct?

You may need to formulate the condition by words to allow us to verify the formula.

@rotabor yes you are right but the last condtion ($T$8:$T$500=$B$3)) is all in the active sheet not comparng with stopwork sheet

@rotabor in words it should be =SUMPRODUCT(('Stop Work'!$D$8:$D$500=$C10)('Stop Work'!$K$8:$K$500="Open")('Stop Work'!$C$8:$C$500=$B$2)*($T$8:$T$500=$B$3))       (1) to check if C10 in sheet1 = any cell in stopwork sheet column"d" and (2) check "K" in stopwork sheet = "open" and (3) check "C" in stopwork sheet = B2 in sheet 1 and finally (1)  in sheet1 "T" cell to be empty or equal to B3 which is empty also

Still not clear. I can recommend you put this formula into an empty column to have possibility to debug it. Then provide us with results.

It seems to me the last condition should be ($T10=$B$3).
I can suggest you to divide the formula by its parts and put onto the worksheet to allow debug possibility:



I've edited the question and shared a link with a live copy from my file to check

It seems to me the last condition should be ($T10=$B$3).

Wowww SIMPLY YES it is - you got it pro - thank you so much ooooooooh finally it was so simple OMG
